# Error with Generics when compiling with Maven, but works fine in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

The code below works normally (compile and run) with Spring Tool Suite (version 3.9.2) and Java JDK 1.8. This is a regular Java web application with Spring Framework with Maven in a project / sub-project structure.

The class below belongs to the "core" module (sub-project):

```
package my.core.util;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public interface StreamUtils {

    /**
     * To filter unique by a key
     */
    static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
        final Set<Object> seen = new HashSet<>();
        return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
    }
}
```

The code (FileServiceImpl.java) that uses the method above belongs to the "web" module:

```
List<DcType> dcTypes = Lists.newArrayList(quote.getDCTypes());
List<DcType> distinct = dcTypes.stream().filter(StreamUtils.distinctByKey(DcType::getId)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But, if I run the Maven build it fails with the following error message:

```
[INFO] my ................................................. SUCCESS [  2.161 s]
[INFO] my-core ............................................ SUCCESS [01:45 min]
[INFO] my-web ............................................. FAILURE [  3.007 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project my-web: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/dev/workspace/my/my-web/src/main/java/my/web/service/FileServiceImpl.java:[43,35] cannot access my.core.util.StreamUtils
[ERROR] bad class file: C:\dev\workspace\my\my-core\target\my-core-1.16.4-SNAPSHOT.jar(my/core/util/StreamUtils.class)
[ERROR] undeclared type variable: T
[ERROR] Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

Here is the Maven plugin pom file configuration snippet in the main (root) pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-proc:none</arg>
            <arg>-Xlint</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
                <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Interestingly that code (StreamUtil) is used in a different project normally.

Comment: Is your Maven plugin configured properly? Try to run a command 'mvn -v' in terminal to see If it is installed properly. Also check for Maven paths in your CLASSPATH.

Comment: The error you've posted is not consistent with the code: `cannot access com.my.core.util.StreamUtils` is not related to the class you've posted (which is in package `my.core.util`). Can you post the correct code or check what's wrong with the real referenced class/interface?

Comment: Forget about package names because I changed them to hide confidential info. If I comment the second line in FileServiceImpl.java the code compiles and run fine. Maven has been working since always. No other change was made in the project.

Comment: Eclipse uses a more permissive approach to generics than the actual java compiler. The main difference is that eclipse can guess that two (not defined) generics (<?>) can be the same, based on their context (it implicitly assigns the `?` to a variable and compares them with the other `? `.